# Google Analytics Sub Sub domain visit logged as homepage visit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, subdomain, multiple-domains, profiles

I currently have my Google Analytics setup to monitor each sepearate subdomain on my site.

I have over 180 subdomains each with their own Google Analytics profile.

These subdomains have their own subdomains and the problem is that it keeps recording the visits to sub sub domains as visits to the homepage "/"

*I know this because I checked it in "Real Time > Overview"*

***Domain structure***

**subdomain:** test.domain.com

**subsubdomain:** info.test.domain.com

I have enabled sub sub domain tracking in each profile but it doesn't seem to affect the results!

My Google analytics js is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.test.domain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Any ideas?